# Tell Java to use Windows keystore

Tags: java, windows, certificate, keystore

Our customer is using its own Root CA for internal applicatins. The certificate is in the Windows Keystore but not in the Java Keystore. How can I tell my Java Web Start Application to use the Windows Keystore for searching the valide cert for SSL connections? Importing the cert into each Java Keystore is no option!

EDIT: Main reason I want to use the Windows keystore is to verify the certificate of my signed application

Comment: I do not think you can. If importing the cert into each Java Keystore is no option, then it sounds like you have no option.

Comment: Java is not able to use the Windows keystore? For me this makes no sense. But thank you anyway for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will search for the certificate in the JREPATH\lib\security\cacerts so you have to add it there if it is not an option then I guess you won't be able to use the application

Comment: Luckily there is a workaround for ignoring the verification of SSL certificates. But the main reason I want to use the Windows keystore is to verify the certificate of my signed application.